# Python if, elif

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

It's really basic stuff but it gets on my nerves; 
Why this code doesn't work properly?

```
for i in range(0, 101):
   if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
      print '{} Three'.format(i)
   elif i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
      print '{} FiveThree'.format(i)

   else:
      print "{}".format(i)
```

Is it because of conditions? So if I want to write the code in this form I must  write the complicated condition first and then the simple one?

Comment: also, how do you know that the code "does't work properly"?

Comment: Indentation is critical in Python; if you aren't wunderbar, stop guessing what indentation he is *actually* using and let him fix it.

Comment: What do you *expect* the code to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: @wunderbar Your first condition is more general than the second. So you'll never get to `print '{} FiveThree'.format(i)` Swap first and second conditions.

Comment: It works but it doesn't write "FiveThree" only Three.

Comment: Your code as written won't even run. Please provide the actual code.

Comment: Consider i = 30. Since you're using `if-elif`, you satisfy both first and second conditions, but your code will not go inside the second condition due to the `elif`.

Comment: FIZZ BUZZ!!!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz : "Fizz buzz has been used as an interview screening device for computer programmers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any number that is a multiple of both 3 and 5 will make the first `if` condition true and will never be checked against the second `if` condition.

You should flip the conditions:

```
for i in range(0, 101):
    if i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        print('{} FiveThree'.format(i))
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        print('{} Three'.format(i))
    else:
        print("{}".format(i))
```

But this is wasteful. It checks `i % 3 == 0 and i != 0` twice.

I'm leaving the optimization as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Your second condition is subset of first condition, so if will never go in that block. Change the order of conditions, it will work

```
for i in range(0, 101):
    if i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        print '{} FiveThree'.format(i)
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        print '{} Three'.format(i)
    else:
        print "{}".format(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if`, `elif`, `else` clauses are mutually exclusive. One option is to put the strongest conditions first as DeepSpace suggests. Another option is to have multiple levels of conditions.

```
for i in range(0, 101):
   if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
       if i % 5 == 0:
           print '{} FiveThree'.format(i)
       else: 
           print '{} Three'.format(i)
   else:
       print "{}".format(i)
```